# Trying to click 2 checkboxes but not able to do so (Selenium Java)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, logical-operators

Site : https://www.myntra.com/men-tshirts

```
`WebElement brand = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='brand-more']"));
        brand.click();
        
        WebElement select_brand = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Search brand']"));
        select_brand.sendKeys("H");
        
        List<WebElement> select_HRX = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//label[@class=' common-customCheckbox']"));
        
        for(int i=0; i<select_HRX.size(); i++) {
            String brandText = select_HRX.get(i).getText();
//          String[] arr = brandText.split("\\(");
            String[] arr1 = brandText.split(Pattern.quote("("));
            System.out.println(arr1[0]);
            if(arr1[0].equalsIgnoreCase("HRX by Hrithik Roshan") && arr1[0].equalsIgnoreCase("HERE&NOW")) {
                 select_HRX.get(i).click();
                 Thread.sleep(2000);
                 break;
            }
        }`
```

// trying to click 2 checkboxes based on condition not able to do any suggestions ??

Answer (score 0):

Here

```java
arr1[0].equalsIgnoreCase("HRX by Hrithik Roshan") && arr1[0].equalsIgnoreCase("HERE&NOW")
```

You should change from `&&` to `||`  i.e. from logical AND to logical OR operator since each of 2 desired elements you want to click will contain first **OR** second text, not **BOTH** of them.
In case you know the anount of checkboxes you want to select you can add counter, like the below:

```java
counter = 0;
if(arr1[0].equalsIgnoreCase("HRX by Hrithik Roshan") || arr1[0].equalsIgnoreCase("HERE&NOW")) {
    counter++;
    select_HRX.get(i).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    if(counter>1){
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Doing so as above suggested still only first element is clicked not the second one.

Comment: You are right, I'm sorry. I added a counter to select all the required elements and only then to break the loop

Answer (score 0):

There's a better, easier, and faster way to do all of this without loops, etc. You need to build your locators using the brand names you are looking for instead of grabbing all elements and then looping to look for a match. It's also a good practice to wait for elements to be in the correct state before interacting with them to avoid unexpected exceptions, etc.

The basic flow is...

1. Navigate to the page
2. Click the Brand search icon
3. Enter Brand #1
4. Click the checkbox next to Brand #1
5. Wait for Brand #1 to show up as filtered on the page (this is important)
6. Clear the Brand search box
7. Enter Brand #2
8. Click the checkbox next to Brand #2
9. Wait for Brand #2 to show up as filtered on the page (this is important)

Now both of the desired brands are filtered and the script can continue.

The code

```
String url = "https://www.myntra.com/men-tshirts";
driver.get(url);

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
// click Brand search icon
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.filter-search-filterSearchBox"))).click();
// get the Brand search box
WebElement search = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("input.filter-search-inputBox")));
// search for the first brand
search.sendKeys("HRX by Hrithik Roshan");
// click the brand checkbox
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//label[text()='HRX by Hrithik Roshan']"))).click();
// wait for the brand to show up as filtered
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//ul[@class='filter-summary-filterList'][contains(.,'HRX by Hrithik Roshan')]")));
// clear the search box
search.clear();
// search for the second brand
search.sendKeys("HERE&NOW");
// click the brand checkbox
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//label[text()='HERE&NOW']"))).click();
// wait for the brand to show up as filtered
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//ul[@class='filter-summary-filterList'][contains(.,'HERE&NOW')]")));
...
```